# Fermat's little theorem for groups. $a^{ord(G)}=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$a\in G, a^{ord(G)}=1$ why is this true? And how does applying the theorem of Lagrange say that ord(a) divides ord(G)? G is finite

Comment: For the second question : $ord(a) = Card( \langle a \rangle) | Card(G) = ord(G)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subgroup generated by $a$ is cyclic and has order $n$, the least integer $k$ for which $a^k$ is the identity.

Lagrange's theorem says that $n$ divides the order $N$ of $G$, so $N = dn$ for some $d$. Then
$$
a^N = a^{nd} = (a^n)^d = e^d = e .
$$

Comment: thanks this helps